# Are there superexponential NP-complete problems?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete

Are there any NP-complete problems where the fastest known algorithm solves the problem in superexponential time (like $O(n!)$ time)?  Every NP-complete problem that I am aware of has fastest known algorithms that are all exponential time, but it is not obvious to me whether there is anything preventing such problems from having best-case algorithms that run in superexponential time.

Comment: "Does nondeterministic Turing machine $M$ accept the empty input within time $|M|^{100}$" might qualify.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I’m not sure [how you define “superexponential”](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/99882/152398), could you make it precise for me?

**If you define "super-exponential" as something described in the previous link like $2^{n^c}$**:
In this context, $O(n!)$ (as you described) is something bounded by $O(n^n) = O(2^{n\log n}) \leq O(2^{n^2})$, not super-exponential;
and since $\sf NP \subseteq EXP$, all problems in $\sf NP$ should be bounded by this "exponential time".

**If you define "super-exponential" traditionally, i.e. $2^{O(n)}$**:
In this case, if you can find a $\sf NP$-complete problem $A$ that is not in ${\sf TIME}(2^{O(n)})$, then it's not in ${\sf SPACE}(n)$ either, thus we can know ${\sf NP} \nsubseteq {\sf SPACE}(n)$; but it's still unknown that if ${\sf NP} \subseteq {\sf SPACE}(n)$ now (maybe new results are published? I don't know, and I learn this from [CMU 15-455 hw7](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eodonnell/15455-s17/homework07.pdf) p4, spring 2017 by Prof. Ryan), so I guess proving this is hard.

(In fact this is more like a comment than an answer, but I don’t have enough reputation to do so, sorry about that)

Comment: In literature, superexponetital quite often (but not exclusively) denotes non-single-exponential running time, i.e. running times not in $2^{O(n)}$. For example $O(n!) = O(n^n) = O(2^{n\log n})$

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out; and I have edited my answer for precision. Could you please check it out again? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry for the slow response.  As the above comment remarks, I define superexponential as something not in $2^{O(n)}$ (I call this just exponential time), since all the NP-complete problems I am aware of have worst case complexity in exponential time.

Comment: I would not expect that $n$ alternations can save $O(n^k)$ time for an arbitrarily large $k$ for every problem in $NPC$, did not know that's not proven.